# Не получаетcя сделать картинку кликабельной

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Я пытаюсь сделать картинку на которой текст кликабельной, но она не кликабельна, кликабельна только ссылка в ней (Новые товары и подробнее). Делал`<a href="/newproducts">` перед тэгом  `<div class="col-sm-3 homeBanner">`, все равно элемент картинки целиком не кликабелен.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 homeBanner">
   <div class="row">
      <a href="/newproducts">
         <img class="bgImage" src="/Content/Images/uploaded/homebanner-1.png" alt="" width="293" height="180" />
      </a>
      <div class="row m0 bannerTextArea">
         <div class="row m0 bannerTextAreaInner">
            <h4>Новые товары</h4>
            <h5><a href="/newproducts">подробнее</a></h5>
         </div>
      </div> 
   </div>           
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно увидеть `CSS` кода?

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1** - [pointer-events: none;](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)   -  [Сan I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events)

```css
.b,
.b-pict {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
.b-text {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.b:hover .b-text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <a href="https://www.google.com.ru" class="b-pict">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTXg1oZXhnADWrRUFJnyfaVdR1RI0yNEQSv4pp81lUyKEajafJQ" alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="b-text">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

**2 вариант** - использовать тег `a` для всего блока

```
<a href="/newproducts">
  <img class="bgImage" src="/Content/Images/uploaded/homebanner-1.png" alt="" width="293" height="180" />
  <div class="b-text">
    <h4>Новые товары</h4>
    <h5>подробнее</h5>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Он написал, что он пробовал второй и почему то не сработало

Comment: в tag 'a' не должно быть вложенного тега 'a'

Comment: Я это знаю. Он написал, что переставлял ссылку за `<div class="col-sm-3 homeBanner">` и не работало